# How does one display numeric month labels as month names in a Dygraphs chart?

Tags: r

I'm trying to visualize average monthly data for all 12 months in a `Dygraphs` chart. The issue is that when I visualize the data there's no obvious way to code the numeric month data as month names.

Below is my current code. The resulting chart has numeric months (1-12) as labels on the x-axis. The only change I'd like to make is to label the numeric months with their names instead. (I.e., "January", "February", etc.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(dygraphs)

Month <- month.name

Dollars <- c(936, 753, 731, 667, 643, 588, 948, 894, 997, 774, 745, 684)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Month) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(AvgDollars = mean(Dollars)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Month = match(Month, month.name)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(c(Month))

dygraph(dat2)
```

The answer may be to use Javascript to add the labels to the chart, but I'm unfortunately not experienced with JS at all. Any suggestions here are much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
month <- c(12,3,6,2,3,7)
month.abb[month]
```

Output:

```
"Dec" "Mar" "Jun" "Feb" "Mar" "Jul"
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing that doesn't let me add the data to a dygraphs chart, unfortunately.